# open source large dbf file converter to csv

Tags: document-converter, csv, file-converter

I'm looking for a gratis software that can convert a large dbf file called `gpmouve.dbf` (1 Gigabyte in size) to a csv file.

All the options I found are either not gratis or not working correctly.

I wish to have the dbf converted to csv in one go. But it can be several if needed albeit useless from my point of view.

Thanks

Comment: What does "(1 Go)" mean? Was that supposed to be *gigabyte*? Or maybe there is a database called *1 Go*? Or do you mean it has to happen all in one go (rather than in stages)?

Comment: hi@JohnY, question updated.

Comment: I still don't know what unit of size "Go" is. If you want people to understand, you should either use a standard abbreviation (in English if it makes a difference, since this is an English-language site) or write out the word(s). Not that it matters too much for this question, but it's something you should keep in mind in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to do a slight bit of coding in Python (which seems likely, based on your profile), you could try using either [**dbf**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) or [**dbfread**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbfread).

The former includes an export facility (callable either as a method on the table object or as a module-level function) which can generate a CSV.
The latter has a short, easy-to-understand [code example](https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporting_data.html#csv) for copying to CSV row by row in a loop.

I have not had to work with huge amounts of data, so I do not know if your file size will pose a problem for either package.